# openshift won't load aiml file

Tags: python, openshift, flask-restful

I am working on a customer care chatbot based on aiml using flaskrestful and pyaiml. My problem is when I test it locally it is working, i.e. responding from the aiml knowledge base, when I put it on openshift the python script won't find the aiml file and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

In openshift, if you want your data to be persistent you have to save it in the 'OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR'. I fixed the problem by placing the knowledge base file in this directory instead and referencing this location in my code.